# How to Remove header from datatable at the time of export to Excel?

Tags: c#, closedxml

From a datatable I want to remove headers. How can I remove headers or first row which includes the headers.

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Customers");

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";

        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fname + ".xlsx");

        using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
            MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please let me know whether the answer solves the problem you 've described. Do you have other issues with the approach I've described? Cheers!

Comment: Ganesh, what @SergiiZhevzhyk is politely trying to say is that you should play by the rules and mark an answer as the official answer if it solves your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 15):

If you don't want to see the headers in the worksheet, don't add the whole table, but only the data. For example, the task is to add all rows of the `dt` table starting from the first cell of the first row in the worksheet:

```
var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Customers");
ws.FirstRow().FirstCell().InsertData(dt.Rows);
```